# Get template parameter from file

Tags: c++, file, class, templates

I have two classes:

1. A non-type templated class Foo
2. A non-templated class Bar which contains a member of Foo, where the template parameter should be read from a file.

From what (I think) I know, this doesn't work because the template parameters of the non-templated class are set at compile-time, so they would need to be static consts.
I don't see how I can achieve that, since some evaluation (i.e. reading file, extracting value) has to happen before I can provide the parameter value. 
Nonetheless, is there a way to achieve something similar?

I want to avoid templating the second class since the user has (in theory) no knowledge of the file, which should be looked up when the program is executed. The file will not change during run-time.

The situation is thus something like this:

```
// templated class
template <int A>
class Foo {
  public:
      Foo() : A_(A) {};
      void print () { std::cout << "The value of A is : " << A_ << std::endl; }
  private:
      int A_;
};

// non-templated class
// This won't work, just showing the idea:
class Charlie {
    public:
        Charlie() {
            A = loadFromFile("myfile");
        }
        void print () { 
            std::cout << "Called from C: " << std::endl;
            C_.print(); 
        }

    private:
        int A;
        Foo<A> C_;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your template definition is wrong should be template< typename A > and declaration of A _A as well; Additionally it is expected that type A has overloaded stream operator <<. In class Charlie Foo< A > _C; won't compile, type A is not declared. In short no way :)

Comment: @RobertWadowski There is nothing wrong with his class, other than that it's a little superfluous keeping a member that holds the template value.

Comment: @RobertWadowski Sure! But it has nothing to do with what you were saying. `A` does not need to be a type, and it should not be `template <typename A>`, nor does he need to overload `operator<<`.

Comment: @RobertWadowski Well, it's just an int. std::cout knows how to output ints ;-)

Comment: Then we back to no point using templates ...

Comment: You should read up on template non-type parameters. They can be very useful! But there is no way of telling whether that is the case here.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a simplified version of what you're trying to do. That's generally a good thing, but I'm getting a feeling that the thing you're actually trying to accomplish can be solved in a better/simpler manner, and we're all misled because [your question is about the solution you think is the right one, rather than about what is the best solution to the problem you're actually trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So what do you need this for?

Comment: Yes, the example is of course simplified. The real application is that I am using a templated Eigen class to determine the dimensions of the matrices being used. Eigen uses different methods depending on whether the matrices are initialized as dynamic or not. So, I need my matrices to be fixed-size ones, but don't know the size a priori. Hence the cunundrum.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have *template parameters read from file*, or otherwise determined at runtime.

Template paramters, inherently need to be deduced/calculated at compile time. No other way, sorry!

The idea of template parameters is that they can be optimized at compile time, so resolving them can't be defered to runtime.

Comment: @6502 None really, but being beyond perception of the OP's questioning scope.

Comment: @6502 Would be a good idea, to provide a concise example, how it can be done just with language inherent tools, and no external source file generation tool needed. Unless you're giving such, your point is much useless in practice,

Comment: My answer is not really that different from yours... except that I'm also trying to explain why this is not possible in C++ (providing some historical context). I said that in C++ cannot be done. Fullstop.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C++ metaprogramming power is way too weak for this kind of process.

While there's nothing wrong in what you are asking (i.e. do some compile-time computation using real tools like opening a file and read some data) this is totally impossible with current (and IMO also future) C++.

In your example moreover seems you need to read the value at run-time and you're still considering compile-time and run-time separate phases.
The only solution I can think to that avoids code generation at "runtime" would be make `Bar` a base class and pre-instantiate derived classes for all the usable values of the number you need to pass. This way you could just select the specific derived class to instantiate at runtime. Note however that this is most probably a nonsense solution for C++, where you also risk serious code bloating if attempting that.

However in C++ it's impossible to read a file even if the operation needs to happen at compile time and you're NOT asking code generation at runtime.

To solve this kind of metaprogramming problems the only solution is to generate the code from a **separate program**. I've personally found Python being a great tool to generate C++ but any language with some text processing power can do the trick.

C++ metaprogramming is just about templates, i.e. "stupid" this-for-that replacement in function and class skeletons. For some reasons a few feature were added that combined with the extremely complex syntax rules of the language happened to bring (IMO involuntarily) turing-completeness-power to this very primitive approach.

This wouldn't have been bad per se, but unfortunately for some strange psychological effect (inexplicable for me) this also meant that any attempt to add real metaprogramming power was dropped and instead all C++ gurus went on experimenting with this new toy that was built by mistake.

You could use recursion to simulate loops, SFINAE and specialization to simulate conditionals, recursive type lists to simulate data structures... They also stressed the compilers incredibly and obtained for example to raise the recursion stack for template instantiation to be able to do more tricks.

This love for pointless puzzles is what directed all "modern" C++ research on metaprogramming and therefore we're here, decades after, still unable to do trivial tasks like reading from a file or enumerating the members of a class at compile time (or even at runtime... C++ doesn't have reflection either because those guys didn't find yet a way to simulate that too using SFINAE).

You have [compile-time rational arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio) in the standard library, however...

Comment: Ignoring your random bitter axe grinding: "The file will change during runtime"?

Comment: @Yakk: I'm not sure I undestand the question... why do you see a big problem if I'm given the ability to even read `time()` at compile time? Of course one could use that ability in stupid ways... but you can even use `break` in stupid ways or give stupid names to variables... so?

Comment: The OP wants to read a value at runtime, not at compile time.  Hence most of your axe grinding is not relevant?  python won't help: shipping a compiler and creating a .so or .dll on the fly would.

Comment: @Yakk: you're right. He's basically asking to generate code at runtime. Not that this has to be a problem (there are languages in which it's not)... but clearly outside the metaprogramming abilities of C++ by far. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the answer is simple.  Make `Foo` not a template.

`Foo` gains nothing from being a template in your case.

Now on the surface this seems like a legalistic misreading of your question, it strikes at the heart of the issue.  You can refactor the parts of your code that vary at runtime, and those are not them become template parameters.  You are reading an int from a file: it is a runtime parameter.  You can do most everything you can do at compile time at run time via interfaces, type erasure and the like.  In theory you can build a runtime type system as powerful as the compile time one, but we call this writing a new language.  ;)

The compile time templates give you checks on things you know at compile time, and allow some optimization opportunities (as more is known at compile time) and safety (ditto).

When you do not know the value of the template parameter, or the range, or anything, these checks are meaningless, and hence needless.  Make the parameter a runtime one, not a compile time one.

A specific example of what you are doing can lead to a specific solution.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int A) : A_(A) {};
  void print () {
    std::cout << "The value of A is : " << A_ << std::endl;
  }
  int A_;
};
struct Charlie {
  Charlie():C_{loadFromFile("myfile")}{}
  void print () {
    std::cout << "Called from C: " << std::endl;
    C_.print();
  }
  Foo C_;
};
```

which matches behaviour you asked for exactly.  Not the *way* you asked, but that way was pointless given the practical problem.

"magic switches" can be used to dispatch from runtime to compile time code.  Double dispatch is trickier, as it is at runtime, and you'll need similar compromises.  Type erasure (like `sts::function`) lets you abstract state needs into clean interfaces that behave like "the same" type.  Generated jump tables keep costs low.